# Subquery Listagg get errors: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this query for getting the inventory data from product, and it is need to be done in one column so i am using this list aggregation query (additional info: [Select subquery that return multiple rows as string (one column) in table (Oracle SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686205/select-subquery-that-return-multiple-rows-as-string-one-column-in-table-oracl)). But in some data getting some errors: result of string concatenation is too long. How to optimize this query and solve this error? (I need the change that only in this subquery, because query is used in others function) Thank you

```
SELECT K.PRODUCT_NO, ..., (SELECT i.OPTIONS
    FROM PRODUCT p , ...
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ITM.PRODUCT_NO
            ,LISTAGG(NVL2(ITM.OPTION1, ITM.OPTION1 || (chr(13)||chr(10)), '') || NVL2(ITM.OPTION2, ITM.OPTION2 || (chr(13)||chr(10)), '') || NVL2(ITM.OPTION3, ITM.OPTION3 || (chr(13)||chr(10)), '') || NVL2(ITM.OPTION4, ITM.OPTION4 || (chr(13)||chr(10)), ''), ',') WITHIN
        GROUP (
                ORDER BY ITM.itm_no
                ) AS OPTIONS
        FROM ITEM ITM
        GROUP BY ITM.PRODUCT_NO
        ) i ON (p.PRODUCT_NO = i.PRODUCT_NO)
    WHERE P.PRODUCT_NO = K.PRODUCT_NO) as OPTIONS,
    (SELECT i.OPTIONS
    FROM PRODUCT p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ITM.PRODUCT_NO
            ,LISTAGG(NVL2(QUANTITY, QUANTITY || (chr(13)||chr(10)), '0'))  WITHIN
        GROUP (
                ORDER BY ITM.itm_no
                ) AS OPTIONS
        FROM ITEM_INVENTORY ITM
        GROUP BY ITM.PRODUCT_NO
        ) i ON (p.PRODUCT_NO = i.PRODUCT_NO)
    WHERE P.PRODUCT_NO = K.PRODUCT_NO) as QTY
    from PRODUCT K
```

Comment: One option would be to upgrade to Oracle 12cR2 which does provide support for handling overflow [find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2#handling-overflow-errors). Not being entirely facetious: Oracle 11g is not an actively supported version.

Comment: The project using oracle 11g and can't be upgraded

Comment: I suspected that was the case, which is why I posted it as a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xmlagg method can be used to aggregate strings.

Example.

```
select rtrim(
           xmlserialize(content extract(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, object_name || ',') order by object_id), '//text()')
                        no indent)
         , ',')
       , object_type
    from user_objects
group by object_type;
```

In your case first subquery will be look like this.

```
  select ITM.PRODUCT_NO
       , rtrim(
           xmlserialize(
             content extract(
                       xmlagg(
                         xmlelement(
                           e
                         ,    nvl2(ITM.OPTION1, ITM.OPTION1 || (chr(13) || chr(10)), '')
                           || nvl2(ITM.OPTION2, ITM.OPTION2 || (chr(13) || chr(10)), '')
                           || nvl2(ITM.OPTION3, ITM.OPTION3 || (chr(13) || chr(10)), '')
                           || nvl2(ITM.OPTION4, ITM.OPTION4 || (chr(13) || chr(10)), '')
                           || ',')
                         order by ITM.itm_no)
                     , '//text()')
             no indent)
         , ',')
    from ITEM ITM
group by ITM.PRODUCT_NO
```

Here you can find more method
https://www.programmingmusings.com/index.php/2015/05/22/string-aggregation-in-oracle-sql/